# Run again Task which isFaulted

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I am running a task, which should work continuously.

I have a while(true) loop which should check this Task has not ended. When it ends I want to run it again.

What can I do when it throws an exception or the Task ended because it `IsFaulted` or `IsCompleted`?

```cs
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{                
    while (true)
    {
        //do something
    }
});

while (true)
{
    if(task.IsFaulted)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    if (task.IsCompleted)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: A Task can't run again, it represents a *single* execution. A task is a *promise* that something will complete in the *future* and possibly return something. In any case, what would `Start` do with a task returned by an IO operation? There are no threads there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true) // Infinite retries
    {
        try
        {
            // Do something
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log the exception, but swallow it, so we retry
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i have a few tasks, some are While(connection == true) so this tasks can be ended. And i wanted to have support for this in 1 place.

Comment: @mdlejtecole What's the problem? In the tasks which can be ended, put that condition. Nothing's stopping you

Comment: @mdlejtecole tasks aren't threads. They don't get started and stopped like threads. In fact *threads* themselves can't be restarted

Comment: So this is the only way to keep my Tasks alive? Dont give them end?

Comment: @mdlejtecole The other way would be something like `var task = Task.Run(DoWork); ... if (task.IsFaulted) { task = Task.Run(DoWork); }`, but I'd opt for just keeping the Task running.

Comment: At last i add Task to method, and run again this method. I think It is better solution for my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a delegate which create task and run it. Then in case of task.IsFaulted you can create by delegate another one task. Some mapping between current instance of task and delegate should be also implemented. Few lines of pseudo code:

```
// deletgate
Func<Task> createDoSomethingTask = () => Task.Run(() =>
{
    // do something
});

// --- create task
Task doSomethingTask = createDoSomethingTask();

// --- in other place you can check status, if task should be re-run, then use delegate
if (doSomethingTask.IsFaulted)
{
    doSomethingTask = createDoSomethingTask();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, at last i just put Tasks in method and rune again this method. I dont prefer use delegate for the mathod in the same class.